# Numpy split unequally

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have this array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I've been trying to make something like this:

Split this array into 3 (unequally) and
I want it to return something like this:

1. 1st element -> 1st array,
2. 2nd element -> 2nd array,
3. 3rd element -> 3rd array,
4. 4th element -> 1st array,
5. etc.

```
[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]
```

I tried something like this

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

new_arrays = np.array_split(arr, 3)
print(new_arrays)
```

but It splits it like this:

```
[1 ,2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]
```

I tried hsplit, It kinda works, but requires equal division, which is not possible for my dataset.

Comment: hi there! You're going to have to be more precise about what you want to do. What exactly do you mean by "split an array into 3 unequally"? Do all three groups have to have roughly the same size, or can they be arbitrary? And what is the exact problem with `np.array_split`? Is it because the elements are sequential, but instead you want them to be randomly assigned to each group? Please update your question to reflect exactly what you're trying to do and why the result you got using `np.array_split` isn't satisfactory. I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know what proper terminology in English means it, but for example If I want to have 3 new arrays, I want the 1st element to go to the first array, the 2nd element to the second array, the 3rd element to the third array and 4th element to the first array etc... I hope that clears it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can create `n` new lists and then use `itertools.cycle` to append values to each sublists:

```py
from itertools import cycle

def my_split(arr, n):
    out = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for v, l in zip(arr, cycle(out)):
        l.append(v)
    return out


lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

new_arrays = my_split(lst, 3)
print(new_arrays)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly how I wanted it.